# .htaccess of WP directory and .htaccess in other directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running WordPress site dedicated to games on my hosting. In between of wp-* folders, there are several other folders (my folders) with microsite content. It looks like this:

[image]

In myFolder1 or MyFolder2 I want to use Rewrite Rules, to all PHP files in this directory, but Wordpress also uses own .htaccess for all of the directories in root of hosting. I'm doing this, because I want to have pretty url.

In Wordpress .htaccess is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

For example: **www.something.com** runs Wordpress app and in *myFolder1* I have another website with .htaccess. The full address is `www.something.com/myFolder/index.php?page=someContent` and I want to have `www.something.com/myFolder/someContent`.

Could you please help me what can I do and what kinds of rules can I set on myFolder1 or 2 etc.? Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WordPress** htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^myFolder(1|2)(/.*)?$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**myFolder1** htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myFolder1/

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/myFolder1/index\.php\?page=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```